# How to deploy express js with PM2 in Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, express, npm, pm2

I am new for Nodejs. I have developed an application using Expressjs. Now I want to deploy my app to the server and I already bought a server from digitalocean.

I don't have any idea that how to deploy my app via PM2.

Please help..

Answer (score 4):

if you have installed nodejs and pm2 on your server. you just need to run pm2 with your express js application instance.

> pm2 start bin/www

You can find your express js application instance in the package.json file. see in the screenshot below.

[image]

after that, you can run the command to check the running instance of the application.

> pm2 ls

Comment: I do this, then check logs, and it shows that `localhost:4000` is open, but it's not.  Pm is blocking it somehow.  If I run without pm, all is fine.

Comment: Your application is running on 4000 port? In bin/www port number is 4000

Answer (score 2):

After you install nodejs to your server, first you need to install pm2 globally via npm:

```
sudo npm install pm2 -g
```

Then, just run the start command:

```
pm2 start "/path/app.js"
```

Thats it. You can see the project with: `pm2 status`

For more pm2 code I suggest you to take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2

Answer (score 2):

See directly the PM2 deployment page : http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/

You just set the configuration of your server host,user,git etc... and pm2 will deploy it remotly automatically